# how to read every third bit in a byte array

Tags: c#, buffer, byte

I have a byte array of 48 bytes and would like to read every third bit of a byte in this array, how can i achieve this?

this is the output of my device

> 100510000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100460000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100320000
>   10000000 100460000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100320000 10000000 100460000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100300000 10000000 100300000 10000000 100310000 10000000 
>   100310000 10000000 100390000 10000000 100300000 10000000 100320000 10000000 120560000 10000000

Comment: Can you show us some code illustrating what you've tried?

Comment: Take a look at the BitArray class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx

Comment: Do you mean: Every third bit of every byte? And do you want to treat it as an array of 384 bits? And also, must it be fast? (Which precludes use of BitArray)

Comment: The output from your device... is that in hexadecimal? in decimal?

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bytes;
for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] &= 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool BitCheck(byte b, int pos)
{
    return (b & (1 << (pos-1))) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bytes;
for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
   BitArray bits=    bytes[i];
   bool bit3= bits[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[4];

var result = bytearray.Select(input=>new System.Collections.BitArray(input)[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate all the bytes and return the specified bit in a byte.

```
    byte[] myBytes;         // populate here
    int bitLocation = 2;    // Bit number
    for (var i = 0; i < myBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        byte myByte = myBytes[i];
        var requiredBit = Convert.ToInt32((myByte & (1 << bitLocation - 1)) != 0);
        // save the requiredBit somehow
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you want the output as a stream of 1 bits and 0 bits corresponding to the bits in the bytes, treating all the bits in all the bytes as one long stream of bits.)

You can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, };

            foreach (var b in BitReader(bytes, 3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<byte> BitReader(IEnumerable<byte> bytes, int stride)
        {
            int bit = 0;

            foreach (var b in bytes)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    yield return (byte)(((b & (1 << bit)) != 0) ? 1 : 0);

                    bit += stride;

                    if (bit > 7)
                    {
                        bit %= 8;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```